Angular MatStepper completed and next
I'm trying to create workflow stepper. My question about the completed step.
If the step is completed, then I want start from the next step.
For example in my code, you can see then step 1 is completed, but current step it is still step 1 when I load the page:
<mat-stepper linear>   
    <mat-step label="Step 1" [completed]="true">
        <p>Step 1</p>
        <button mat-button (click)="complete()" mat-raised-button color="primary">Complete</button>   
    </mat-step>

    <mat-step label="Step 2" [completed]="true">
        <h3>Step 2</h3>
        <button mat-button (click)="complete()" mat-raised-button color="primary">Complete</button>   
    </mat-step>

    <mat-step label="Step 3">
        <h3>Step 3</h3>
        <button mat-button (click)="complete()" mat-raised-button color="primary">Complete</button>    
    </mat-step> 
</mat-stepper>


